# Python - IO:Error Cannot Identify Image File

Tags: python, io

I'm working on an image to text OCR system and I kept receiving an error on the console stating

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crack_test.py", line 48, in <module>
    temp.append(buildvector(Image.open("./iconset/%s/%s"%(letter,img))))
  File "/Users/seng_kin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2290, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file './characterset/a/.DS_Store'
```

I have a folder in a `../OCR/characterset/` directory which has 26 subfolders representing 26 characters whereby each subfolder contains a .PNG of a character.

The score_test.py is stored in `../OCR/`

**score_test.py Code:**

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import math

****def functions****

iconset = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
           's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

imageset = []

for letter in iconset:
    for img in os.listdir('./characterset/%s/'%(letter)):
        temp = []

        if img != "Thumbs.db": #windows check...
            temp.append(buildvector(Image.open("./characterset/%s/%s"%(letter, img))))

        imageset.append({letter:temp})
```

I saw other solutions on the website but all is related to the absence of `from PIL import Image`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.DS_Store` is a "hidden" file in directories on Mac OS X.

In your `if img != "Thumbs.db"` check, you should add:

```
if not img.startswith('.') and img != 'Thumbs.db':
```

this way you filter out all "hidden" files.